# web component z index

Tags: angular, web-component

I have an Angular 12 component running in storybook and z-index works fine.
When I compile it into a web component z-index isn't working anymore, do you guys have any idea why? or how could I replace z-index with something else? I tried with transform and translate but didn't work out.

Comment: I believe this is not a thing you can solve it directly into the web-component due to the `shadow dom`. Have you tried applying the z-index rule the the wrapper of the component in your FE?

Comment: I will try that and let you know

Comment: Try to add css style dynamically  after view loaded.